# Change sql server from visual basic form

Tags: vb.net

I want to let the users change the sql server connetion manually from a settings form because the application will be used in many company

i tried this:

i create a string in settings "sqlservername"

then in the loading form i put a textbox "txt_sqlservername" and savebutton

the button event

```
My.Settings.sqlservername = Me.txt_sqlservername.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox("Server Name Was Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Videos Database - New Server Name")
    Me.Close()
```

and this is my connection string

```
Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=My.Settings.sqlservername;Database=Videos;User=sa;Pwd=123456;"}
```

when i open my main form nothing shown

any help?

Comment: it is better practice to not allow end users to change the connection string but rather make the application deployable with the updated settings. however if you must, you can do this by using the ConfigurationSettings class. - good example here: https://mahtabrasheed.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/read-write-into-app-settings-and-connection-string-section-of-app-config-using-c/

Comment: @Ahmedilyas please could you take a look on my edit

Comment: you have not followed the link I had supplied. your code is incorrect and you have not shown the full code either.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a form that asks for user input for the connection string and then save the connection string in the application settings.
You can use this connection string from the settings every time you define a connection in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The string formatting is wrong where the connection is defined.Make correction like shown below:

Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=" & My.Settings.sqlservername & ";Database=Videos;User=sa;Pwd=123456;"}